# How do I set a fixed height for a given section of a grouped style table view?

Tags: ios, tableview

We did come across numerous posts about controlling the height of header and footer sections of a grouped table view. What we are looking for is a way to control the entire height of a given section of a grouped table view. In other words the number of rows returned for that section could be just two but we would like the table to show up holding five cells with the last three cells empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you would need to return 5 from `numberOfRowsInSection:`, then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, detect that you don't have a *real* cell and get a "blank" one to use (which can/should be a re-used prototype).

```
if(indexPath.row >= [[myModelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count]) {
  // use a 'blank' cell...
} else {
  // build a 'legit' cell...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. We did think about this. Since this looked more like a hack we were just wondering if there was another solution.Thanks!

Comment: It's kind of a "hack" situation, don't you think? The way you phrase the question, you explicitly mentioned 3 'empty' cells. This is how you would do that. I'm not sure about the details of your requirement, but you also have the option of manipulating the height of each cell conditionally... something like `if(cells_in_this_section * DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT < MIN_SECTION_HEIGHT) this_cell_height = MIN_SECTION_HEIGHT / cells_in_this_seciont;` This is a different effect; not sure exactly what you want.